# Load a test image for unit testing

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I'm writing a test for a class that loads an image and does some color manipulation.
The image is loaded with

```
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

If I run the app everything is fine and the images are loaded as expected. I added a unit test  that shall use a specific test image to be loaded during the test. If I run the test fixture the image is not loaded. What I read so far is that the method imageNamed always loads from the app bundle's resource folder. How can I change this to the bundle of my test?

Answer (score 14):

In Swift 3.0 you would do:

```
let bundle = Bundle.init(for: NameOfYourTestClass.self)
let image = UIImage(named: "TestImage", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

Where `NameOfYourTestClass` is the name of your test class ✌️

Answer (score 5):

Made a handy category for this.

```
image = [UIImage testImageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Goes like:

```
@interface BundleLocator : NSObject
@end

@interface UIImage (Test)
+(UIImage*)testImageNamed:(NSString*) imageName;
@end

@implementation BundleLocator
@end

@implementation UIImage (Test)
+(UIImage*)testImageNamed:(NSString*) imageName
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[BundleLocator class]];
    NSString *imagePath = [bundle pathForResource:imageName.stringByDeletingPathExtension ofType:imageName.pathExtension];
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that you have an image in the test bundle that you want to use only in tests (i.e. a test fixture), go have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602876/accessing-a-uiimage-inside-a-ocunit-test-target).

You can tailor that answer to get the NSBundle of your actual app by using `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[SomeClassThatExistsInTheAppOnly class]]`. This lets you specifically target the app bundle from a test bundle.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use this (in Swift):

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: MyClass.self)
let img = UIImage(named: "TestImage", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

To change app bundle:

let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "org.cocoapods.ACSPLib")

let photo = UIImage(named: nameofThePhoto, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)

the bundle identifier

[bundle identifier for pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK38M.png)

Answer (score 0):

well, one option would be to add that resource to your test(app).

personally, i just use paths (`initWithContentsOfFile:`), data (`initWithData:`), and such. this may involve introducing a few parameters -- but that's *good* in many cases, because that parameter can be used to test more input image files (if you like) while not changing/cloning/repackaging the apps much.

Comment: But this means that you change the production code for testing purpose, which should not be the case especially not for framework parts that are made to make your life easier ;).

Comment: @truni so… you're trying to convince me that you're using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` for your framework's parts, and that's the way it should be? using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` in that context is a really bad idea for several reasons. if you're writing a faux-ios-framework, use NSBundle and specify or find your faux-ios-framework's resource directory. then use something other than `[UIImage imageNamed:]`. then create another bundle for your test variation and run your tests over all bundles.

Comment: and in that context, it's not changing the code for testing purpose, it would be changing your code because your code was doing the wrong thing. instead of creating a new bundle all the time, you could pass these parameters to your framework's interfaces (public or private).